# Why does std::remove for file always return -1?

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to remove a file if exists. So first I test if the file exists and if it does I remove it using `std::remove`. test.json contains some json related txt in it. I also have `#include <cstdio>` included.

```
   std::string file_to_remove = "test.json";
   std::ifstream f(file_to_remove.c_str());

  if (f.good()) {
    int val = std::remove(file_to_remove.c_str());
    std::cout << "\nRemoving file : " << file_to_remove  << " : ret val : " << val<< std::endl;
  }
```

I was expecting the ret val to be `0` but I am getting `-1`

My current output is :

> Removing file : test.json : ret val : -1

I have also made sure the file is closed.

Comment: Have you read the documentation https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/remove ?

Comment: If you have the file open, it's a little hard to remove.You may need to close it first.

Comment: Check [`errno`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno) (using e.g. [`strerror`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strerror) or [`perror`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/perror)) if the function fails (which it indicates it does when it returns `-1`).

Comment: "I have also made sure the file is closed." <- no, you did not as per snippet provided.

Comment: Do you think creating `f` doesn’t open the file?

Comment: After adding `f.close();` before `std::remove` ret val now is `0`

Comment: @mato  You should research how to determine if a file exists without opening the file.  Opening a file and checking the `good` return value is unnecessary and a roundabout way of doing this.

Comment: Note that checking for existence does not guarantee that the file will exist when you try to remove it. That is, checking first is pointless since a well-behaved program needs to handle the possibility of failure anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation of [`std::remove()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/remove) (emphasis mine):

> **​If the file is currently open by this or another process, the behavior of this function is implementation-defined** (in particular, POSIX systems unlink the file name although the file system space is not reclaimed until the last running process closes the file; **Windows does not allow the file to be deleted**).

Meaning if the file is open, it will not remove the file if you are on Windows. It will return an error (e.g. -1).

Any other platform could really be anything since it is implementation defined. I'd research your platform/compiler and see what the result of calling `std::remove()` on an open file is.

> After adding f.close(); before std::remove ret val now is 0

That makes a lot of sense, since `f.close()` closes the file. The file is now closed, it it can be removed.

Answer (score 5):

You try to remove an open file.

In Posix systems (like Linux), it's fine to remove an open file. It will continue to exist on disk and you can still use it for as long as you have it opened, but it will be invisible to others since its directory entry has been removed. When you close the file, it'll be gone.

In Windows you can not remove an open file. Check the error code with `perror` or `GetLastError`.

Comment: Windows might let you delete a open file, depends on what the original opener allowed. The C++ library might not even try, implementation specific perhaps.

Comment: @Anders `CreateFile` with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` I guess? I assume most implementations just try to remove the file but since a process opening a file in Windows must specifically allow others to delete it, it'll rarely succeed :)

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Sadly Windows does not use it for running processes so you can never delete a running .exe.

Comment: @Anders, Windows does use delete sharing when opening an executable as a process image or shared library, which is why we're allowed to rename a running executable. (Renaming a file requires opening it with `DELETE` access, since it's an atomic unlink-relink.) However, the memory manager disallows deleting an executable image, which is why the error in this case is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (5) instead of `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` (32).

Comment: Also, `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` with a normal delete is different from POSIX, since a normal delete in Windows doesn't unlink a file from a directory until the last handle is closed. Until then, any handle with `DELETE` access can be used to undelete the file. The kernel in Windows 10 (in particular the NTFS filesystem driver) now supports POSIX semantics when renaming and deleting files (e.g. `FileDispositionInformationEx`), which has POSIX-like behavior when combined with delete sharing. But these new operations aren't used by classic Windows API functions such as `DeleteFileW` and `MoveFileExW`.